# How to exclude multiple folders matched by wildcards from a find search

Tags: find, aix, search

I wish to find all files and folders except/excluding folders starting with 'tmp' and 'logs' under '/app/test' directory using `prune`

Thus I tried the below command.

```
find /app/test -type d \( ! -name logs* \)  -o \( ! -name log \)  -o \( ! -name tmp* \)  -o
\( ! -name tmp \) -prune | tee /tmp/findall.log
```

But I see top folder included in the find result like below:

```
/app/test/Admin/tmp/data/pm.trp
/app/test/Admin/tmp/wond/iqc.log
etc ...
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Wildcards used as patterns with `find` must me quoted to stop the shell from expanding them. Do you have names matching `tmp*` and `logs*` in the current directory when you run this?  Also, you seem to apply `-prune` to everything _not_ matching the names.

Comment: i put single quotes `find /app/test -type d \( ! -name 'logs*' \)  -o \( ! -name 'log' \)  -o \( ! -name 'tmp*' \)  -o
\( ! -name 'tmp' \) -prune | tee /tmp/findall.log` but still /tmp/ is showing in the results. Not sure what you said about `prune`.

Comment: You want to `-prune` all names matching `tmp` etc., right? But you have `! -name tmp -prune`, i.e. "prune names that are _not_ `tmp`".

Comment: if I remove the `!` from the command then find does not get all the files but only displays folders with the names logs & tmp. My requirement is simple... i want find to show all files except files which are in folder names starting with tmp or logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from not quoting words that contain filename globbing characters, you also have inverted the sense of all `-name` tests, resulting in pruning the names that do *not* match these names and patterns from the search tree.

Instead:

```
find /app/test -type d \
    \( -name 'logs*' -o -name log -o -name 'tmp*' -o -name tmp \) -prune -o \
    -print | tee /tmp/findall.log
```

The `-prune` test would, without `-print`, still print out pathnames of things matching up to that point.

Comment: This works .... one query I still have is what if I want `find` to get files under a folder called `config` (exact match) but exclude all folders which have names starting with config****

Comment: @Ashar You would use something like `find . -type d -name config -print -o -name 'config*' -prune`

Comment: @Ashar Sorry, you said all files under. Then `find . -type f -path '*/config/*' -print -o \( ! -name config -name 'config*' \) -prune`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```bsh
find /app/test -type d \( -path "*/log*" -o -path "*/tmp" \) -prune -o -print | tee /tmp/findall.log
```

Note that when using `-path` the full directory name is being matched; hence the use of the front `*` wildcard in the glob patterns.

Note also that `"*/tmp"` matches only paths with directories named exactly `tmp`, and not directories named `tmp2` or `tmporary` for example; while `"*/log*"` will match any path including a directory name starting with `log`.

`-prune` makes `find` skip all directories matched within the parenthesis.